# Calculate probability of number based on previous numbers in a non-random sequence

Tags: probability

I have a large number of number sequences of different lengths consisting of 1s and 0s indicating whether an action has occurred, like:

0111001111101

00010001111

01111111011111

What I would like to calculate is the probability of finding a 0 after a sequence of 1, such as the probability of finding a 0 after a single 1, after two 1s, after three 1s, etc, across all these sequences. I would basically like to know whether the probability of a 0 increases or decreases with a longer sequence of 1s.
I have looked at conditional probabilities but haven't found a solution that matches my problem.

This might be a simple question, but I haven't been able to find the solution by myself so hopefully someone here can help.

Comment: I can say one thing: if there is independence in the sense that the digits on other spots do not influence the probability on 0 or 1 on a fixed spot then the probability of finding a 0 after $n$ 1s does not depend on $n$ (so there is no increasing or decreasing). If there is no independence then more information is needed to calculate the probabilities you mention. Btw, welcome at Math.SE and enjoy your coffee (just like me).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that the digits are not independent. This is output from behavioural research where the probability of carrying out a certain action is dependent on whether this action was performed on a previous occasion. What I want to see is how performing an action on multiple occasions will influence the probability that it will or won't be performed at the next occasion.

Comment: So you have the sequence of 0 and 1, and you want to use that sequence to find the probability distribution of switching from 1 to 0 at a specific point as a function of how many consecutive 1's there are leading up to that point?

Comment: I allready suspected. In order to make any calculations at first some mathematical model must be made of the reality you mention. But how? Not really my territory and your so-called "simple question" turns into a "complicated question". I hope you will get some respons here, but I am not very optimistic about that. Good luck. Btw, if you want to address someone in a comment then start with @ and type the name. Then the person gets a signal.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @drhab Thanks for your comments! You might be right that my simple question is not so simple after all, I might just have to do some more research to try to figure this one out. I thought that maybe I was just missing some aspect of conditional probability, but I could very well be wrong about that.

Comment: @Bjorn Try to make a FROM-TO table. FROM 0, 00, 000, 0000,...,1,11,111,1111,..- TO 0, 00, 000, 0000,...,1,11,111,1111,.. and count all the changes appearing in your data.